# Send AS3 score variable to PHP file

Tags: php, actionscript-3, variables

I have a variable called score in my flash game and I want to post the score from my flash game to a php file called test.php;  the last part of the AS3 code when game is finished is:

```
function gameFinished(){
gameOver.play();
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
Mouse.show();
again_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playAgain);
}
```

Here is where I want to publish my score var to the php file so I can use it in a leaderboard; I have read many tutorials but having a really hard time. Could you please guide me a little bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS3:

```
function gameFinished(){
   ...
   again_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playAgain);

   var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   var req:URLrequest = new URLRequest("test.php");
   var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
   requestVars.score = 150; //your scroe here
   req.data = requestVars;
   req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
   urlLoader.load(req);
   urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, scoreSent);
}

function scoreSent(e:Event){
  trace("score sent to php");
}
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST["score"])){
  //submit the score;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mgraph, your code works and I really appreciate it, the only problem is that a new window is opened when the post is made, I mean the test.php file opens in another browser window, any idea on how to avoid that?

Comment: It shouldn't open a new window, is there somewhere a navigateToURL?

Comment: @i'llbdevsomeday make sure you do not have `naviagateToURL("test.php");` in your as3 script

Comment: Hi mgraph and Zhafur, I do not have the navigateToUrl but modified your code little bit probably on a wrong way, check this:`code` function postScore()
{
  
 var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 

  myVariables.score = score;

  var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.php");

  myRequest.data = myVariables;
 
  myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 urlLoader.load(myRequest);
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, scoreSent);
 

 


}
function scoreSent(e:Event){
  trace("score sent to php");
}

Comment: Hi mgraph, your script is working perfectly, actually I tried at my laptop and everything is working fine so I went back to my pc, cleaned cache, cookies and browsing history and voila! it is working nice, neat and fast. You saved my life pal, I owe you big time! Have a great day! The problem was because before you gave me your code I was trying during several hours with a function calling the navigateToURL stuff